# Passing all the entries from a login form to database at once

Tags: php, database

I have created database in phpmyadmin( in wamp server). I have a lengthy login form to pick up the entries from.
Just a part of code of login form:

```
            <label>

           <span>First name</span>

           <input type="text" size ="25" placeholder="Your Name" class="input_text"onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
    value="" name="f_name" id="name"/>

        </label>

         <label>

           <span> Middle Name</span>

           <input type="text" size ="25" class="input_text" placeholder="Father's name"  name="m_name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
    value="" id="middle name"/>

        </label>

         <label>

            <span>Last Name</span>
           <input type="text" size ="25" class="input_text" placeholder="Surname"  name="l_name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
    value="" id="last name"/>

     <br>
```

How I am retrieving entries using php (just one entry shown as an  example):

```
    if(isset($_POST['f_name'])){
$name .= $_POST['f_name'];}
```

and then pass it to database using:

```
mysql_query($sql,$con)
```

My question is instead of adding each entries separately, Is there a way of shorter coding than this ? I mean can we pass all the elements' name attributes at once to some function ? Or any such way of reducing this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have solved this issue.  I place the form fields inside a variable.  For example, in your html form, instead of

```
<input type="text" size ="25" class="input_text" placeholder="Father's name"  name="m_name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
    value="" id="middle name"/>
```

use

```
<input type="text" size ="25" class="input_text" placeholder="Father's name"  name="m_name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''"    
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue" 
    value="" id="login[middle name]"/>
```

This way, in your php code, you can iterate through the login items.

```
foreach($_POST['login'] as $key=>$loginItem)
```

Comment: This approach makes validation extremely hard and is a really bad example on how to do it.

Comment: Flesh, I disagree.  As long as you know the keys that you set, you can do all of the validation you want inside the loop.  The nice thing about this approach is that if you want to add additional fields, you do not need to change the php, just the database and the html.

Comment: How? With a `switch` or `if-else`? Via dynamic function calls based on the key? No matter how you do it, it's hard to read, hard to maintain or kills performance. Sorry, but it's a bad approach. I don't say that it doesn't work, of course it does, your answer is perfectly valid. But it an approach that will make life hard for you. But I have something <i>similar</i> in my object oriented code, but it works slightly different and is extremely easy to maintain and self-validating.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the only requirement is, that everything goes into a single table.

HTML form stub:

```
<input name="param1">
<input name="param2">
<input name="param3">
```

Basic example for insert:

```
<?php

mysql_query(
  "INSERT INTO `table` (`param1`, `param2`, `param3`) VALUES
    ('{$_POST["param1"]}', '{$_POST["param2"]}', '{$_POST["param3"]}')"
);

?>
```

Please make sure that all data is properly escaped and validated (the example is only an illustration and ultra insecure).

---

I'd like to extend my answer because of the accepted answer which basically show how not to do it because any data is simply taken directly into the database. The most basic rule of thumb in any software is **“never trust any user supplied data”**. You **have to** validate and sanitize anything and everything.

Let's consider the following login form:

```
<form action="/login.php" method="post">
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Very basic, but it's already better than most login forms that utilize usernames which are also visible on each users profile. Using the email address is more secure, because most websites hide the users email address, ensuring that only the user who registered knows the email address she or he used to sign up.

Now to the validation part. We only have two entities to consider, but still, we have to validate them!

```
<?php

// Use proper PHP filters to validate the user input.
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR);
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password", FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW, FILTER_REQUIRE_SCALAR);

// Only continue if both are valid.
if ($email !== false && $password !== false) {
  // Use prepared statements and let the database take care of escaping!
  $user = $db->select("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?", "s", [ $email ]);

  // Don't tell the user trying to sign in which of both entities was wrong!
  if ($db->numRows === 0 || password_verify($password, $user["password"]) === false) {
    throw new LoginException("We either don't know the email address or the password was wrong!");
  }

  // Well, everything is fine, go on ...
  session_start();
  echo "Welcome {$user["name"]}!";
}
// Be as helpful as possible.
elseif (empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
  throw new LoginException("Email and password are mandatory!");
}
// The password can't be invalid, so it must be the email address.
else {
  throw new LoginException("The email address is invalid!");
}

?>
```

If your form becomes more complicated your validation becomes more complicated and that's a good thing.